# How to select count of two distinct columns?

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I would like to do a count of the total number of distinct COMPONENT_ID and PACKAGE_ID returned from this SQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COMPONENT_ID, PACKAGE_ID FROM BILL;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
select count(distinct (COMPONENT_ID || PACKAGE_ID))
  from BILL;
```

Provided `||` is the string concatenation operator.

Comment: won't this return `COUNT(COMPONENT_ID)` * `COUNT(PACKAGE_ID)`?

Comment: If I have the following table: (a, b), (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)
then `select count(distinct concat(a, b)) from mytable` will return 4, but `select count(*) from (select distinct a from mytable union select distinct b from mytable) subtable` will return 2. Also, using concat will mean that rows like (12, 3) and (1, 23) will be considered identical and will not be counted correctly.

Comment: @Adam: true. But the answer is just a general idea of how the problem could be approached. You get the idea, analyze your data, and use it to solve your problem. I.E. you can use a separator with the string: `COMPONENT_ID || 'SOME#WEIRD#SEPARATOR' || PACKAGE_ID`. Thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: That's true, but you're still not calculating `COUNT(COMPONENT_ID)` + `COUNT(PACKAGE_ID)`, you're calculating `COUNT(COMPONENT_ID)` * `COUNT(PACKAGE_ID)` because the `DISTINCT` operator will generate every possible combination of `COMPONENT_ID` and `PACKAGE_ID`

Comment: I'm sorry Adam. Don't know where you get that `COUNT(COMPONENT_ID) * COUNT(PACKAGE_ID)` from. Where did you get that distinct will generate every possible combination of `COMPONENT_ID` and `PACKAGE_ID` from? Aren't you confusing `distinct` with a `cross join` operator? Just trying to follow your line of thoughts here...

Comment: it will happen when you use `distinct` with the concat function. At least this is how the `distinct` keyword works in MySQL. I recommend that you try this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*)
from
(
    select distinct component_id, package_id
    from yourtable
) as distinctquery
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT component_id FROM bill
    UNION SELECT DISTINCT package_id FROM bill
)
```